# Using Queue for loops (Python)

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I have trouble understanding how the following code works:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import os, time, random


def write(q):
    for value in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
        print 'Put %s to queue...' % value
        q.put(value)
        time.sleep(random.random())

def read(q):
    while True:
        value = q.get(True)
        print 'Get %s from queue.' % value

if __name__=='__main__': 
    q = Queue()
    pw = Process(target=write, args=(q,))
    pr = Process(target=read, args=(q,))

    pw.start()
    pr.start()
    pw.join()

    pr.terminate()
```

It seems that `pw.join()` synchronizes `pw` and `pr` but I just don't know how it works. I thought `pr.start()` proceeds after `pw.start()` is completely finished, which means `Get %s from queue` could only be received after three `Put %s to queue...` had been printed. I also thought `pool()` is used for multiprocess and `process` only is used for single process, but now it appears I am totally wrong.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `pool` is to create a group of processes. `Process` creates a single, separate process. Both are multiprocessing constructs.

Comment: "I thought `pr.start()` proceeds after `pw.start()` is completely finished" - `pw.start()` is "completely finished" once it has started `pw`. It does not wait for the `pw` process to end.

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you, but when I delete pw.join(), I cannot get any `Get %s` message, can you tell me what role pw.join() plays?

Comment: @JieyuYou: That waits for the `pw` process to finish.

Comment: What would the point with Process be if you had to wait for it to finish?

Comment: @user2357112 Can you be specific? I still don't understand the reason why `pr` fails to proceed(`Get %s from queue` is not received) if `pw.join()` is deleted.

Comment: @JieyuYou Is this your code? If yes, you should know what it does. If not, well, don't run someone else's code if you don't know what it does! Anyway, the last line of your program terminates the process. If you don't wait for the sending and receiving to happen, you just shut down the process meaning no communication happens.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thank you! Now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

First, your question should be entitled something like "How does join work in python"

join() blocks the calling thread (which in this case is the main thread) until the process whose join is called is terminated. See the definition [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

So in your code you are blocking the call of pr.terminate() until pw finishes. When you remove pw.join statement, process pr terminates soon after starting and that is why you do not see any "Get ..." messages.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand.